# tried to replace a letter in csv and received the below please

Tags: shell, replace

please`enter code here` help to understand why the cmd does not end and give the result

```
awk '{sub("Y","'Y",$0); print}' master.csv
```

i receive > and then nothing

Comment: Please post your full code and explain your problem in question, not in heading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the single-quote, like this:

```
awk '{sub("Y","'\''Y",$0); print}' master.csv
```

Alternatively, use `\x27`, the hex code of a single quote. (You could even use the octal code `\47`.)

```
awk '{sub("Y","\x27Y",$0); print}' master.csv
```

Comment: the beow is my csv file where i have to replace Y with 'Y 

YV100376 1 2 YV100377 1 2

but i get 
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1



pls advise